# SQL Server select the max value from one column and check if the value exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I am working for an INSERT statement.

Here's my steps:

**Step 1**: select the highest value from a column in `table A`. The value in that column is not serialized. Then add +1 (e.g. highest value is 45, then the end result for this step is getting 46)

**Step 2**: Then, check if the 46 exists in `table B`

**Step 3**: If the number exists in `table B`, then increment by 1 again and check again.

Any idea how can I code this?

Comment: Hi WhileLoop, I think you need While Loop for that

Comment: That strongly sounds like horrible RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing which is a really bad idea for SQL Server. For something like this, use the **proper database means** - use an `INT IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE` object (SQL Server 2012 or newer) to handle something like this in a proper, relational way

Comment: I agree. Too bad the database design is in this form when it was handed to me. There are 000 - 999 as primary key while in the middle there are empty slot. (e.g. 030, 031, 037, 040...) Also, I could not re-design the database because the column is linked to thousands of other table and system.

Answer (score 2):

If possible make Use of "Sequence". It generates sequence of numeric values and can be shared among tables.

Otherwise

```
SELECT MAX(MAXVAL) FROM 
 (
    SELECT MAX(VAL) AS MAXVAL FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(VAL) AS MAXVAL FROM TableB
 )T
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can write recursive CTE to achieve this.

Here is the sample code

```
;WITH CTE AS 
            (
                    SELECT MAX(VAL)+1 AS MAXVAL FROM TableA
            ),CTE2 AS
           ( SELECT MAX(VAL) +1 AS MAXVAL FROM TableB            where exists (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE MAXVAL=TableB.MAXVAL)

)

SELECT MAXVAL FROM CTE2
```